# Python Auto run files on startup

Tags: python, autorun

I have made an alexa like program on python. Now, I want it to auto run when I start my computer and take inputs and give outputs as well. How do I do it?

Comment: Which OS are you on?

Comment: I am using Linux

Comment: Ok, wait i posted it for windows

Answer (score 0):

### - For linux

First make sure you add this line to the top of your python program.

`#!/usr/bin/python3`

- Copy the python file to /bin folder with the command.

`sudo cp -i /path/to/your_script.py /bin`

- Now Add a new Cron Job.

`sudo crontab -e`

This command will open the cron file.

- Now paste the following line at the bottom of the file.

`@reboot python /bin/your_script.py &`

- Done, now test it by rebooting the system

You can add any command to run in the startup in the cron file.

Cron can be used to perform any kind of scheduling other than startup also.

### - For Windows

Navigate to C:\Users\`username`\Appdata\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

Place your complied `exe` file there, it will be executed on startup.

To make exe from py, first install the pyinstaller module `pip install pyinstaller`.

Now run the command in the folder where the python file is `pyinstaller --onefile your_script.py`

Comment: Its not working...also I want to open the file from pycharm-community..I guess the file has been copied to /usr/bin because I repeated the steps and it wanted to overwrite the saved file... but the final command in crontab is not working